# How to find a shortest path in a directed graph which must pass through specific nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I have a directed graph with less than 600 nodes, and each node's edge number is less than 8.
Now I need to find a path in this graph which must pass through some given nodes(<50). The order of passing given nodes is free.
I know it's a NPC problem, but I don't know how to solve it.
An approximate solution is also acceptable.
Thank you!

Comment: [strangely on-topic](https://xkcd.com/69/)

Comment: Does your path start and end at a specific node? Do you need to find a lot of such path with different start/end-nodes for a constant graph?

Comment: wouldn't a bfs solution do the trick for you? take the first node from your path. check its neighbors and repeat till the set of traversed nodes doesn't contain all the nodes in your path [you mentioned it must pass through some nodes, so I am assuming the path can contain other nodes too.]

Answer (score 1):

Compute the shortest ways between all pairs of the specific nodes. Then create a new graph that only contains those nodes, with the length of the shortest paths as distances. Now, the problem is "reduced" to Travelling Salesman.

(TSM has a fast 3/2-approximation that utilitizes minimal spanning trees and a matching, if that is good enough - the 50! possibilities are too much in any case)